# PubNub based opensource web chat

Tags: chat, pubnub

Have anybody heard of some opensource, or one that can be bought, client-side (web, android, ios) chat based on pure pubnub or pubnub ChatEngine?

The reason I'm asking is that it looks like PubNub gives a reliable backend, but it doesn't come up with UI that we can just use as drop in replacement for our current chat, that doesn't perform well, and we don't really have time to build UI from scratch.

I found many examples of really simple chats, but it's still a long way from that to fully functional chat that we need to replace.

We have a multi-room chat, with users being able to access only some subset of rooms and also open one-on-one chats. Similar to Slack, but with way fewer features.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-made UI for [ChatEngine](https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/chatengine/?devrel_so=pubnub-based-opensource-web-chat) using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/). The example has 1 to 1 chats which can also be chat rooms. There is a tutorial for building the app with ChatEngine on the PubNub Website:

Tutorial:
[https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/chatengine/vuejs/chat-app/](https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/chatengine/vuejs/chat-app/?devrel_so=pubnub-based-opensource-web-chat)

Live Demo:
https://ajb413.github.io/chatengine-vue-chatbot-1to1/

GitHub Repository:
https://github.com/ajb413/chat-engine-vue

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This is only a basic example. I need something much more powerful, similar to slack. Given pubnub has history and access management, there could be a totally client-side app with permission system and room access security.